# Assigning a value to a global variable inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

```
a = 2
def alter_a():
    a = a * 2
    return a
```

Why doesn't this work? I know it won't change the value of the global variable, but can't it work inside the function?

Sssign a new value to a... which is the old value * 2. Why isn't this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The `a` inside the function lives inside the function scope, if you want to reference the outer one use `global`:

```
a = 2
def alter_a():
    global a
    a = a * 2
```